# New-PSDrive : The network path was not found

Tags: shell, powershell, permissions, remote-access, remote-server

I am having an issue to connect to the remote server using `New-PSDrive`. The remote server is Windows-based, and only `userA` has access to write.

By saying that, the following code throws an "access denied" error:

> Access to the path '$remoteServerPath' is denied on line3

Code:

```
New-PSDrive -Name remote -Root $remoteServerPath -PSProvider FileSystem 
$destination = [IO.Path]::Combine('remote:', $fileName)
Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $destination -Force
```

Now, I am trying to include credential information, but I get a different error!

> The network path was not found on line3

```
$secpass = ConvertTo-SecureString 'myPassword' -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ('domain\userA', $secpass)
New-PSDrive -Name remote -Root $remoteServerPath-PSProvider FileSystem -Credential $cred
$destination = [IO.Path]::Combine('remote:', $fileName)
Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $destination -Force
```

Can anyone please help me out? **Powershell Ver. 5**

Comment: Please show the `$remoteServerPath` assignment in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you creating a PSDrive for this task?

```
& NET USE Z: \\server\path /user:domain\UserA 'PASSWORD'
Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination 'Z:\' -Force
& NET USE Z: /D
```

If you have their plaintext password, this should work just fine.

Comment: I am getting the following error:
"The FileSystem provider supports credentials only on the New-PSDrive cmdlet. Perform the operation again without
specifying credentials"

Comment: @Adrian using this example verbatim?

Comment: It looks like only New-PSDrive supports credential, and copy-item does not. is it because of my PS version? (5)

Comment: @Adrian Certainly not.  You can verify these things by using `help command` in the console and seeing the syntax.  Are you trying to map the network drive as a different user than what is logged in?

Comment: Yes. that's correct. I am 'userB' who does not have write access to the $Destination folder, but only userA does. I even tried running PS as a different user (userA), but no luck...

Comment: I see now.  Let me edit my response with something that should work then.

Comment: @Adrian If you want to change the file's name at the destination, just edit the string to be `Z:\Filename.ext`